# Doctrine associations Integrity Constraint when persisting

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, associations, entity

I have a number of `@ManyToMany` association mappings that work as they should, however when trying to persist an entity with either a bidirectional `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` association, Doctrine throws the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'uid' cannot be null'
```

**Entities/EntityBase.php**

```
namespace Entities;

class EntityBase{

    /** @Column(type="integer", columnDefinition="INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL") */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    protected $created;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    protected $updated;
}
```

**Entities/User.php**

```
namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\UserRepository")
 * @Table(name="users", indexes={@Index(name="id", columns={"id"})})
 */
class User extends EntityBase{

    /** @Id @Column(type="string") */
    protected $uid;

    /** @Column(type="string", nullable=true) */
    protected $first_name;

    /** @Column(type="string", nullable=true) */
    protected $middle_name;

    /** @Column(type="string", nullable=true) */
    protected $last_name;

    /** @OneToOne(targetEntity="Entities\Interest", mappedBy="user") **/
    private $interest;
}
```

**Entities/Interest.php**

```
namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\InterestRepository")
 * @Table(name="interests", indexes={@Index(name="id", columns={"id"})})
 */
class Interest extends EntityBase{

    /** @Id @Column(type="string") */
    protected $uid;

    /** @Column(type="string", nullable=true) */
    protected $interests;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Entities\User", inversedBy="interest")
     * @JoinColumn(name="uid", referencedColumnName="uid")
     **/
    private $user;

    public function setUserId($uid){
        $this->uid = $uid;
    }

    public function setInterests($interests){
        $this->interests = $interests;
    }
}
```

The above association should indicate that a user can have one interest and an interest belongs to one user.  I'm using `uid` as the primary key instead of `id` because the datasets that are being persisted are coming from an API in which all users have a unique `uid`.  I'm not sure why I get `'uid' cannot be null` seeing as I've dumped the dataset and the `uid` is definitely being passed as a string.

Here is my interaction code:

```
//Example
$data = array('uid' => '10298564', 'interests' => 'Creative Art');

if(!$interest = $entityManager->getRepository('Entities\Interest')->findOneBy(array('uid' => $data['uid']))){
    $interest = new Entities\Interest();
}

$interest->setUserId($data['uid']);
$interest->setInterest($user['interests']);

$entityManager->persist($interest);
$entityManager->flush();
```

When I run this with the `@OneToOne` association between User and Interest, I get the `Integrity Constraint violation` error when persisting.  However if I remove the association, the entity persists correctly and updates the database.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The doctrine references mapping can set reference only identifier fields. In your example field "uid" - is not identifier field. And why your create index @Table(name="interests", indexes={@Index(name="id", columns={"id"})}). This index will be auto created with doctrine. For better solution: create a custom trait for control created and updated field and use itself in each entities.

Comment: @ZhuKV - thanks for taking a look, is there a method of using a custom string as an identifier field?

Answer (score 0):

As per your entity classes, Interest is the owning side of the relationship. When you try to persist the Interest object, it expects a User object to persist as well. This is maybe because you have not allowed null for the Interest's User mapping.

In order for the persist to happen either attach a User object to the Interest object or allow null for that mapping (which is not recommended).